# ProgressView inside a CollectionView header

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a progress view inside my header that updates continually in sync with the songs current progress. I have the logic for the progress bar working fine. Its just I can't seem to get the header to display the progressView. I need to get the exact cell for the header and set the progress in accordance with my timer. Like below. But the below code gives me a crash on accessing the specific indexPath. How do I access the indexPath for the header?

```
- (void)updateTime
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    CurrentArtistHeader *cell = (CurrentArtistHeader *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration);
    float current = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);
    cell.progressView.progress = (current/duration);
}

-(void)playCurrentArtist:(NSDictionary *)currentArtist
{
    NSString *streamString = [currentArtist objectForKey:@"stream_url"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@", streamString,CLIENT_ID];
    NSURL *URLFromString = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URLFromString];
    [self.player play];
    self.playerIsPlaying = YES;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[self.player currentItem]];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What needed to be done was tag the header cell in viewForSupplementaryElement then set the progress with my timer using the tagged header.

```
    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if ([kind isEqualToString:CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader]) {
            CurrentArtistHeader *header = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                                   withReuseIdentifier:@"header"
                                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (self.hostCurrentArtist[@"user"]) {
                header.tag = 50;
              } 
      }
}


 - (void)updateTimeAndProgressView
    {
        if ([self.player currentItem]) {
            CurrentArtistHeader *header = (CurrentArtistHeader *)[self.collectionView viewWithTag:50];
            float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentItem.duration);
            float current = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime);
            header.progressView.progress = (current/duration);

            if (header.progressView.progress == 1) {
                [header.progressView setProgress:0.0 animated:YES];
            }
        }
    }
```